# What is a source code in C#?

Tags: c#

My professor is asking me to submit my source code as my assignment in Visual Studio. I am working on a Windows Form application in C#, is my source code the actually code that I have been working on? Or is it like the background code that I don't edit or touch?

I'm only asking because my professor is completely useless when you need to ask her a question because she never replies in time and I need to submit my assignment in a few hours. I have searched the web for source code but I need a specific answer.

I don't want to read 50 pages just to find out the code I need to submit was the code I was working on. Thank you everyone for your help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: "the code i need to submit was the code I was literally working on" It *likely* is

Comment: C# code itself, the code you wrote

Comment: Don't you think you should be asking your professor? But, yes, just zip the folder with your solution in it, and submit it.

Comment: if you want to keep it small either delete the `obj` and `bin` folder from your solution before zipping up or even better grab a `.gitignore` from [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) use git and send here the repo ;) (of course this might get dangerous if your prof does not know how to use git ... but then maybe you should take another course in the first place ^^)

Comment: @Candide if you read my post you wouldn't have said that.

Comment: @ehh, thanks, i was really unsure if it was the code i was working on, or the background code that loads everything. Im still learning how to manipulate Visual Studios as it seems to have a mind of its own sometimes.

Comment: @tyress , feel free to tell me which code then

Comment: Just put your laptop to sleep with the project open in visual studio, mail it to the professor and hope for the best.  Make sure the battery is fully charged before sealing the parcel.   (I joke but I swear to God it nearly came to this with some of my teachers...)

Comment: @SprJD7903 you already have two answers?

Comment: @SprJD7903 I wasn't sarcastic. Strictly speaking, the term "source code" means just the text code that you have written. But, in this context it has a looser meaning. It means, give me everything I need to execute what you wrote. Sometimes, while inappropriate, source code could imply libraries that are dependencies, or assets such as images. The professor could have meant "don't include the binary files (*.dll)", that's why I mentioned that you should ask your professor what he/she intended.

Comment: You have to submit all files(including auto generated code).Submit the whole directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is the stuff you wrote in Visual Studio. Anything you need to actually build/compile the application is usually what we would call source code. You need to make sure your professor can also compile the application in Visual Studio just like you could, so send over any files that she would need to do that.

Comment: Phillips, So its the code that, when I double Click on the button "Close" and VS it creates the "private void", is in fact the source code? Not the background code that loads everything together?

Comment: Zip the whole folder, the folder that contains your .sln solution file and every subfolder. Optionally you could delete the bin and obj folders but keep everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your solution file in visual studio, choose "Open the folder location". It will open the physical location of your files under the solution. Completely zip the contents in that path, submit it to him. Simple as that. You already knew it and we are making sure for you '-)

Answer (score 0):

Source code is the raw code that you write when making an application or program. In short what your professor needs is your code.

Zip your solution folder which you find at
Documents => Visual Studio 2013/2015 => Projects => {name of your project}
This is the folder that you zip and send to your professor

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**SOURCE CODE ---> (COMPILER) ---> MACHINE CODE**

**SOURCE CODE :**
Source code is any collection of computer instructions (possibly with comments) written using some human-readable computer language, usually as text. As a programmer you write source Code in your C# editor.

**MACHINE CODE :**
Machine Code is a set of instructions executed directly by a computer's central processing unit (CPU).

**COMPILER :**
A compiler is a computer program (or a set of programs) that transforms source code written in a programming language (C# in your case) into another computer language (the target language), with the latter often having a binary form known as Machine code.